# Measuring 0.1mm accuracy of very short distance (< 5 or 10mm)

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, measurement

I need to measure a very short distance (< 5 or 10mm) of a rotating shaft which will eventually move to one side by a few mm.
I would connect this to an Arduino or similar.
Could someone recommend a cheap option and a more professional option for the sensor?

Comment: That's a bit of a broad question, but usually for these accuracies: point a laser at an angle at a mirror fixed to the end of the rotating shaft, and use an optical sensor to measure the deflection angle.

Comment: There are many ways to make proximity sensors depending on what you need. look up proximity sensor. for your application a "reflective-photo-interrupter" would probably do.

Comment: Need to know more about mechanicals. Do you really need to measure distance specifically?  Could you use a beam break solution of some sort?  And which way is the motion you need to measure - parallel or perpendicular to the shaft axis?

Comment: There are many projects published on extracting electronic output from cheap digital calipers, the challenge would be more measuring to a *rotating* object.  That might make a non-contact method preferable, but these may involve more challenging calibration.  A cheap laser is likely to have a spot larger than your allowable error so would require some creativity to usefully apply.

Comment: I do need the distance. The rotating part is what makes it a challenge, the recommended gage is a great option but for prototyping I would really like to find a cheaper option, then once approved I can ask for the money for the expensive part. Any other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1):

There is a device called a Linear Variable Differential Transformer which is used for displacement measurements on the scale which you describe. However, in order to use this method, it would be necessary to have the measurement core slide in a frictionless manner on the rotating shaft, so that the radial displacement is obtained. This particular requirement, along with the associated expense, may preclude its use in this application.

Comment: Plan B: If an excursion limit for the shaft deflection can  be established, then try using a laser pointer and a photo-transistor to  make a type of limit alarm. A convex or magnifying lens might be used to sharpen the laser beam or bring it to a focal point.

Comment: There's no need to comment on your own post. You can edit it to add to the answer.

Comment: Could you give me some image or link? I don't fully understand your option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Measurements on rotating mechanisms are easily done with mechanical gages.
The kind with a spring-loaded plunger, and electronic interface, is
represented by Mitutoyo model 542-172, with RS-422 (electrical) output.
[image: electronic position gage]
The less expensive mechanical versions of these gages are
widely available, with clock-like dial face readout.

Comment: Whit3rd that's a very good option. I was hoping for the professional option to be a bit less expensive. Do you know if there are any other cheaper options with a less accurate resolution? I just need 0.01mm

Also, any DIY option you can think of?

In all cases I need to be able to read it via a microcontroller ( like an Arduino).

Thanks a lot

Comment: At significant software cost, you could get a dial-face or LCD gage and a videocamera ($20 or so for hardware), but precision measurement and digital interface is selling well at high prices, so don't expect much at the low end.   The depicted item  is at the high end of the industry.

Comment: I see there is a counter display which combines with this sensor, although the the sensor already outputs rs422 as you said. Can rs422 be read by an Arduino? Do I need to figure out the protocol? Or should it be a standard thing to be read? I have authorization to buy it and want to make sure I will be able to read it. Thanks

Comment: @Serge -I'm unsure how to read out this model (there's a remark in the web page "every... gage is bundled with a dedicated counter"), you'll want to talk to sales reps.   RS422 is supported by a variety of receiver and transmitter ICs.